# Can a "case" in "switch-case" javascript ignore errors and run "default" if one of "case" an error occurred?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop, switch-statement

In this case, I want to a `case` in `switch-case` ignore anything errors and run a `default`, in one of the cases, I find a file `JSON` and want to convert to `Object` and inside that file `JSON` has lack syntax `,` also `{` and `}` and do `JSON.parse()` also `for in` it will result error, and I want to this error not interrupting another code or ignore the error and run a `default` in `switch-case`

```js
let dataArray = ['image', 'gif', 'audio', 'video'];

for(let i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
  switch (dataArray[i]) {
    case 'image':
      // I want to ignore this error and run "default"
      unknownFunction();
      break;
    default:
      console.log('Default is run');
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default statement in switch is not intended for error handling, it is only meant to be run if all the other cases fail. You might just want to surround the whole switch statement in a try-catch block and use the catch block as your default:

```
let dataArray = ['image', 'gif', 'audio', 'video'];

for(let i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
  try {
      switch (dataArray[i]) {
        case 'image':
          // I want to ignore this error and run "default"
          unknownFunction();
          break;
      }
  } catch (err) {
      console.log('Default is run');
  }
}
```

Comment: wow, thanks, I just found out that `switch-case` is still running without `default`

Comment: @Firmansyah glad you learn something today. Please also note that if you don't define `default` block, the `catch` block won't run when you have unmatched cases.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no way to do that. But you can do a try/catch:

```js
let dataArray = ['image', 'gif', 'audio', 'video'];

for (let i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
  try {
    switch (dataArray[i]) {
      case 'image':
        // I want to ignore this error and run "default"
        unknownFunction();
        break;
      default:
        // Throw unmatched cases into catch block so that you can handle unmatched cases too.
        throw new Error('No matched cases.');
        break;
    }
  } catch(e){
    console.log('Default is run');
  }
}
```

With this, you are basically using the `catch` block as your `default` block, thus all kinds of errors will run the block by default. You can always put more logic into the catch block for more customisations.

Answer (score 1):

You can put `try/catch` around the code that produces the error, and put the `break` statement in there as well. If an error happens, the `break` statement will be skipped, and you'll fall through to the next case.

But if you want to get to the default, this is only useful in the last case before the default. If you have multiple cases, you won't be able to use this in all of them.

```js
let dataArray = ['image', 'gif', 'audio', 'video'];

for (let i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
  switch (dataArray[i]) {
    case 'image':
      // I want to ignore this error and run "default"
      try {
        unknownFunction();
        break;
      } catch {}
    default:
      console.log('Default is run');
      break;
  }
}
```